# SQL Server + retrieve the data without overlapping datetimes

Tags: sql-server, date, distinct, recursive-query, overlapping

I need some thoughts to the best implementation of this case

I have data where there can be multiple  values with start & end datetime, now i need to pull the data without overlapping the dates, below is the sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (
  start_date DATE NOT NULL,
  end_date DATE NOT NULL,
  comments VARCHAR(100)  NULL ,
  id int
);

INSERT INTO table2 (start_date, end_date, id) VALUES
('2011-12-01', '2012-01-02', 5),
('2012-01-01', '2012-01-06', 5),
('2012-01-05', '2012-01-10', 5),
('2012-01-09', '2012-01-11', 5);
```

from this i need the data which is not overlapping for each id

```
('2011-12-01', '2012-01-02', 5),
('2012-01-05', '2012-01-10', 5)
```

Please share me the thoughts on what cane be the best way to implement this ?

Thanks for the support

Thanks,
Manoj.

Comment: Your output doesn't make much sense to me. Why are those two row returned?

Comment: Sorry if my question was confusion few, adding more details here

This is the expected  result set.

('2011-12-01', '2012-01-02', 5),
('2012-01-01', '2012-01-06', 5), -- cannot pick this as it overlaps with the first record, the startdate is in between the first record start and enddate 
('2012-01-05', '2012-01-10', 5), -- we will pick this as we skipped the second record claiming that it overlaps with first record
('2012-01-09', '2012-01-11', 5); -- this get skipped as it overlaps with the above record

Comment: What do you mean by not overlapping? How is the output not overlapped?

Comment: @SeanLange I believe the logic is the following: When partitioned by `id` and ordered by `start_date`, a record can only be invalidated by a previous valid one - because the second record is invalid (because of the first one), it cannot invalidate the third one.

Comment: @ChrisMack if you can decipher any logic out of this you are doing better than I am. They all seem to have the same overlapping pattern to the "previous" one to me. Each new rows starts one day earlier than the row prior to it. Why is the third row different than row 2 or 4???

Comment: @SeanLange Essentially, we're running through the records in order (by `start_time`), and when one is discounted due to an overlap, e.g., row 2, it "disappears", and so won't affect subsequent records. The answer I have posted is working for this, so if you look at that you'll see what I mean. If my logic is correct, and row 3 happened to overlap with row 1, then that would also be invalid, and row 4 would be in the result set.

Answer (score 2):

The output you provide is very unclear. On the first sight you are looking for an intervall, where not other intervall starts within (which would lead to a continued intervall). But your second *expected* line is overlapping with `2012-01-10`?

The following query will return a row, if its end_date is not within another rows intervall... But this does not return your two expected rows, just the first.

```
SELECT * FROM table2 AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                 FROM table2 AS x 
                 WHERE x.start_date<>t.start_date 
                   AND x.end_date BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date
                );
```

I hope this points you the right direction...

Comment: Thanks for the response, i have added more details in comments of my question

Answer (score 0):

The following will do it:

```
WITH cte
AS
(   
    SELECT
        [start_date]
        , end_date
        , comments
        , id
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                [start_date]
                , end_date
                , comments
                , id
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [start_date]) R
            FROM table2
        ) Q
    WHERE R = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        [start_date]
        , end_date
        , comments
        , id
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                T.[start_date]
                , T.end_date
                , T.comments
                , T.id
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T.id ORDER BY T.[start_date]) R
            FROM
                cte C
                JOIN table2 T ON
                    C.id = T.id
                    AND T.[start_date] > C.end_date
        ) Q
    WHERE R = 1
)

SELECT
    [start_date]
    , end_date
    , comments
    , id
FROM cte
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i have aded more details in comments of my question

Comment: It sounds like my answer will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the query is not filtering any data.

Comment: I've posted a new solution using a single query.